# Is it possible to create jar from past releases with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ce

I need a way to automate jar creation for some old releases in gitlab. I wonder if jenkins can help me or not ? And how ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably must be having tags in gitlab for those releases...right. So you can create git based parametrized build which will show you all the branches/tags while doing the build...from the dropdown list you can select the required tag and it will do the creation of jar assuming you have build scripts in place.